# Inline Search Bar Materialize CSS

Tags: css, materialize

**How can I have both my search box and badge horizontally in single row in the navbar ? I'm using materialize CSS**

```
<nav class="orange" role="navigation">
            <div class="nav-wrapper container">
            <a id="logo-container" href="/" class="brand-logo white-text">C.U.P.S</a>
                <ul class="right">
                    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small indigo" href="cart"> <i class="material-icons left">add_shopping_cart</i> Cart <span class="badge white-text" data-badge-caption={{ count((array) session('cart')) }}></span></a>
                    <form class="col s12">
                        <div class="inline">
                            <div class="input-field col s6">
                                <input id="search" type="text" class="validate" placeholder="Search...">
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-field col s6">
                                <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small indigo" type="submit" name="action">Search</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you upload your problem into a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pen/), it is easier for people to try out your code, adapt it and help you. It doesn't take long, I added your stuff in around 5 minutes, with taking care of scripts and links, but it will be a great help for people who want to help you solve your problem.

So, some general stuff about the materialize grid:

- To make text fields inline, you need to add the `inline` class to the `input-field`-div (can be found in the examples of [Materialize Text Inputs](https://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html)). Adding an enclosing div does not work
- Columns only work with an enclosing row, which the `<form>` does not have. This is also part of your problem, more down below
- The grid is based on 12 columns. So the form with `col s12` will take up the complete row
- If you want to split the form 50:50, you need to put the form in their own container. If not, the col will assume, that it is referencing the container around the whole navbar (more about [Grids in Materialize](https://materializecss.com/grid.html)
- An unordered list (`ul`-tags) should always have list-items (`li`-tags) for each individual part of the unordered list

So, regarding your problem: Add list items to your unordered list, one for the badge, one for the search form. Then, you also need to add a div with the `row`-class to your form, as well as a container for the elements to get back into a local context. Add the `inline`-class to the right element, and you are good to go. Here's a [CodePen with a working example](https://codepen.io/mewitte/pen/ZEGjPWO). Hope it helps and you understand why it didn't work before!

edit: update codepen link

Answer (score 0):

Try by this way

```
<nav class="orange" role="navigation">
            <div class="nav-wrapper container">
            <a id="logo-container" href="/" class="brand-logo white-text">C.U.P.S</a>
                <ul class="right">
                    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small indigo" href="cart"> <i class="material-icons left">add_shopping_cart</i> Cart <span class="badge white-text" data-badge-caption={{ count((array) session('cart')) }}></span></a>
                    <form class="col s12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="input-field col s6">
                                <input id="search" type="text" class="validate" placeholder="Search...">
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-field col s6">
                                <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small indigo" type="submit" name="action">Search</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Add **row class** instead of **inline**

Comment: I tried it, didn't work. I'm starting to think the input field is too large and so it pushes the button down